# xcode 3.2.4 (sdk 4.1) unable to install to device

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, ios4, device

I recently installed XCode 3.2.4 to my machine. This comes with iOS SDK 4.1. Annoyingly I can no longer install my app to any iPhone. The option to tick "Device" in the drop down for where to install to is present, but when I click it, it doesn't become ticked. Strangely I can only run my app on the simulator, despite the option to select the simulator not being present.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Tristan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, I'm answering my own question.

What I didn't realise is that there's seperate build configurations depending on wether you click 'info' while selecting your project's title or the project's Target. I had set the project one to SDK 4.1 but not the Target one.

Comment: Also sometimes you should do this inside out (in my case the solution was to set Project's Base SDK to iOS 4.1 and Target's - to iOS 4.0).   And accept you own answer as correct - because it is really correct))

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the iOS Deployment Target in your Debug or Release Build Settings to match the OS version on your iPhone?   Did you set the Targeted Device Family to iPhone?

Comment: Did you set the Base SDK to 4.1 or 3.2?

Comment: Deployment target: I've tried that, but I don't think that should affect it. Besides, I want my project to also be OS 3.1.3 compatible. Thanks though.

Base SDK: I've tried both, but that doesn't affect it either.

Comment: Are both your Project and Target settings set correctly for the new SDK and your device?

Answer (score 0):

All these questions just remind me that something is very confusing in xCode.
And don't let me start talking about all the provisioning misunderstandings