# Upgrading xcode loses simulator option

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xcode 3.2.4 (sdk 4.1) unable to install to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682071/xcode-3-2-4-sdk-4-1-unable-to-install-to-device)

Due to [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717104/running-an-iphone-app-on-the-device-only-shows-a-white-screen) I was having in my project I decided to upgrade my xcode to XCode 3.2.4 iOS SDK 4.1. Now I no longer have the option to pick simulator but instead when I choose 'Device' it deploys to the Simulator!!!

Under 'Project Settings I can select 'Base SDK' as either device or simulator.

I tried uninstalling XCode full and re-installing but to no avail.

How can I get both deployment options back in and working correctly?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with one project, or all projects?

Comment: Currently I only have one active project. If I start a new project with the new XCode I have both options. I reinstalled the previous version today and the Simulator popped back again

Answer (score 0):

Probably something in the Project Settings isn't right.  For each SDK upgrade, you'll have to at a minimum reset the "Base SDK", and usually fix one or two other things.  For the 4.1 update, I had to remove some OS Minimum settings from the SDKs I use.  The compiler command line had two `-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=...` with different values that was causing the compile to fail.

Compare a new project's settings with your current project's settings.